# Wald Statistic with heteroskedasticity on asymptotic inference vs exact inference

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, statistics, heteroskedasticity

I was working on the following proof but I got stuck.

I'm trying to show that the next equality holds:

$$(X'X)^{-1}X'\mathbb{E}_n[\varepsilon\varepsilon']X(X'X)^{-1} = \mathbb{E}_n[XX']^{-1}\mathbb{E}_n[{\varepsilon}^2XX']\mathbb{E}_n[XX']$$

where
$$\mathbb{E}_n[\varepsilon^2XX'] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{\varepsilon}^2_iX_iX_i'$$

I tried to show that

$$X'\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon\varepsilon']X = \mathbb{E}[\varepsilon^2XX']$$

expanding the matrix product from the left hand side, but I ended up with a $p \times p$ matrix and I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Write the matrix product as sum. Seperate offdiagonal part from diagonal part. Assume 0 correlation but heteroscedasticity so offdiagonal part becomes 0.